# jpgraph charset problem

Tags: php, jpgraph

I use `php` [jpgraph](http://jpgraph.net/) library, but there i a small problem with charsets.
lets assume `graph.php` generates the image, and i call it from `some.php`

`some.php`

```
     ...
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     ...
    <img src="graph.php" />
     ...
```

as you see, i set charsets in `some.php`, but it doesn't show the text of the graph, which is in foreign language.(maybe i must set it in `graph.php`? but how?)

What is the problem?

Thanks
UPDATE

even when i try to enter numerical HTML encoding
of the Unicode character from [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1328&names=-&utf8=dec&unicodeinhtml=dec), it doesn't work for Armenia language:/

Answer (score 1):

The meta tag only applies to the content of the page, not to images displayed within the page (even images generated dynamically by your graph.php script)

Quoting from the [jpgraph faq](http://jpgraph.net/doc/faq.php)

> **16 How can I print unicode characters?**
>
> Use &#XXXX; format in your strings
>   where XXXX is the decimal value for
>   the unicode character. You may find a
>   list of Unicode characters and there
>   encodings at www.unicode.org Please
>   observe that the encoding in the lists
>   are given in hexadecimal and these
>   values must be converted to decimal.
>
> Note: If You are working in an UTF-8
>   environment then the characters may be
>   input directly.

Comment: what does it mean? `If You are working in an UTF-8 environment then the characters may be input ` **directly** ??

Comment: It means if your script file (graph.php) is UTF-8, then you can do $graph->title->Set('チュートリアル');

Comment: but how can `graph.php` be utf-8? it's php file, with no encoding type. and when i try to enter characters in `dec` format, doesn't work:/ look at update pls

Comment: Most good file editors and IDEs now allow you to save a script file as UTF-8 (don't try to save it with a BOM header though)... even Windows Notepad has this option now.

Comment: i've tried to save it as utf-8 too, still doesn't work.
for example, when i wrote `$graph->title->Set("&#1330;");`, which is the simbol for Ա in armenian, it show unknown simbol.

Comment: Does the font that you are using support the characters you want to display? That's the solution I found. (Leaving this here for future generations!)